# Rails: Using Jquery for Text_Area character count

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, keyup, charactercount

My goal is to put the keycount in a blank 'p' element above a text_area. Here is my erb and javascript:

```
<div class="field">
  <p id="char-limit"></p>
  <%= f.label :essay %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :essay, :id => "essay-form" %>
</div>
```

(This is all I have in my javascript file by the way)

```
$("#essay-form").on("keyup", function() {
  var charCount = $("#essay-form").val().length;
  //The text in the p element with id char-limit is equivelent to num of chars
  $("#char-limit").html(charCount);
  if (charCount > 10) {
    $("#char-limit").css("color", "red");
  } else {
    $("#char-limit").css("color", "black");
  }
});
```

Only problem is, when I start typing, there is no number of characters count added into the char-limit p element.

Comment: `$(".essay-form")` is a class selector you need to use an id selector `$("#essay-form")`

Comment: and use `keydown` event which is better than using `keyup` event.

Comment: Ok, I changed it to an id selector (silly mistake), and also tried keydown as well, but the text isn't appearing. Any other suggestions? Am I missing something for how to add a new javascript file to rails? I thought the //= require_tree . in the application.js file meant that any new scripts would automatically start working

Comment: if you put your javascript in `/app/assets/javascripts/<controller_name>.coffee` it will read it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function updateCounter(){
    var charCount = $("#essay-form").val().length;
    //The text in the p element with id char-limit is equivelent to num of chars
    $("#char-limit").html(charCount);
    if (charCount > 10) {
        $("#char-limit").css("color", "red");
     } else {
        $("#char-limit").css("color", "black");
     }
 };
```

And

```
  <div class="field">
    <p id="char-limit"></p>
    <%= f.label :essay %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :essay, :id => "essay-form", onkeydown="updatecount()" %>
  </div>
```

Hope this help. :)

Comment: There were a few things I had to change in your code but doing :onkeydown=>"updateCounter()" worked perfectly. Thank you!